# How to fire timer.Elapsed event immediately

Tags: c#, events, timer

I'm using the `System.Timers.Timer` class to create a timer with an `Timer.Elapsed` event. The thing is the `Timer.Elapsed` event is fired for the first time only after the interval time has passed.

Is there a way to raise the `Timer.Elapsed` event right after starting the timer ?

I couldn't find any relevant property in the [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class.

Comment: can you provide a little bit of code? maybe calling the event handler after setting up the timer could do the trick

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just call the `Timer_Tick` method yourself.

---

If you don't want to deal with the Tick callback method's parameters, then just put the code that was in your `Timer_Tick` into another method, and call that from the Timer_Tick and from just after the `Timer.Start()` call

---

As pointed out by @Yahia, you could also use the [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) timer, which you can set to have an initial delay to 0. **Be aware though, that the callback will run on a different thread, as opposed to the callback on the `Windows.Forms.Timer` which runs on the UI thread.** So if you update any UI controls using the [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) (without invoking correctly) it'll crash.

Comment: Seems the solution for me. But if I want to deal with the Tick callback method's parameters, what should I use?  `OnTimer(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)`  My timer instance for `source`? How can I create a new `ElapsedEventArgs` ?

Comment: The `Tick` Event of the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` has a `source` and `EventArgs` parameter, the source would be the timer, just do `new EventArgs()` for the 2nd parameter. If you're using the `System.Threading.Timer`, then for the 2nd parameter just create a new ElapsedEventArgs, setting `SignalTime` to something like `DateTime.Now()`.

Comment: `OnTimer(timerInstance, new ElapsedEventArgs() { ... });` fill the ElapsedEventArgs-fields as you need them.

Comment: @Matten Actually I can't - `ElapsedEventArgs` has no constructor defined. Am I missing a point?

Comment: @Leito yes, `ElapsedEventArgs`'s ctor is marked as internal. So use `null` as second argument and in the handler code `if(e==null) signalTime=DateTime.Now` would yield the same result as initializing `ElapsedEventArgs` with `signalTime=DateTime.Now` (which isn't possible)

Comment: System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew( () => tmr_Elapsed(null, null) );   if you want the non-thread-blocking beahiour.

Comment: The question was about `System.Timers.Timer`, so there is no `Tick`.

Answer (score 27):

I just called the `**ElapsedEventHandler**` with null parameters.

Answer (score 19):

I know this answer is late but if you want your `System.Timers.Timer` to be fired within 100ms (default interval) then you could simply just initialize the `Timer` object without a specified interval, then set the interval within the called function to whatever you like. Here is an example of what I use in my Windows Service:

```
private static Timer _timer;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _timer = new Timer(); //This will set the default interval
    _timer.AutoReset = false;
    _timer.Elapsed = OnTimer;
    _timer.Start();
}

private void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
    //Do some work here
    _timer.Stop();
    _timer.Interval = 50000; //Set your new interval here
    _timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Best answer! Although you don't even need the `_timer.Stop();` bc you set `_timer.AutoReset = false;`, so you enter `OnTimer` with `_timer.Enabled` set to `false` anyway. But it doesn't do any harm either.

Comment: And of course you could also use `new Timer(1)` instead of `new Timer()` to accelerate the whole thing from 100 ms to 1 ms.

Answer (score 16):

Try `System.Timers.Timer`

```
System.Threading.Timer t = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(DoSomething), null, 0, 30000);
```

This starts immediately (0 milliseconds for the first run, 30000 milliseconds for subsequent runs)

see
[System.Timers.Timer docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[System.Timers.Timer constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Threading_Timer__ctor_System_Threading_TimerCallback_System_Object_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Comment: I should have specify that I don't want to use the `System.Threading.Timers` cause I develop a Windows service. Thx anyway :)

Comment: we use System.Threading.Timers in Windows service - are they not allowed or what kind of problems could happen in Windows Service ?

Comment: It is written on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx):   _System.Threading.Timer is a simple, lightweight timer that uses callback methods and is served by thread pool threads. It is not recommended for use with Windows Forms, because its callbacks do not occur on the user interface thread. System.Windows.Forms.Timer is a better choice for use with Windows Forms. For server-based timer functionality, you might consider using System.Timers.Timer, which raises events and has additional features._

Comment: thanks :-) that's what I read too... so there is nothing prohibiting the use in a Windows Service, only that there is another option with more features.

Comment: *Always* favor System.Threading.Timer over System.Timers.Timer, it is a much better timer class.

Comment: @Hans Do you have some references? Links?

Comment: @Leito - ask a question about it, that's the way it works around here.

Answer (score 10):

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
   Timer_Elapsed(null, null);
});
```

After Timer creation/configuration, worked fine for me...

Answer (score 5):

For the first time, the timer will start after 1 second. After that, its interval will be changed to every 30 seconds or whatever...

```
    //main function    
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000);   //initial start after 1 second
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapsedMethod);
        timer.Start();            
    }
    private void TimerElapsedMethod(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) 
    {
        Timer timer = (Timer)sender; // Get the timer that fired the event
        timer.Interval = 30000;      // Change the interval to whatever
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Comment: It's good, because it works, and it's simple.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to raise the event whenever you want (not only just at the moment you start the timer), you can encapsulate a timer in your own MyTimer class. This class exposes the original Timer methods and properties. Furthermore I added an event with explicit add and remove. In this way whenever you add a delegate to the event this is added to both the private MyTimer's event and to the original timer Elapsed event. This means that the timer triggers Elapsed in the usual way, but you can manually trigger the event calling RaiseElapsed (this should sound much simpler looking at the code).

```
public class MyTimer
{
    Timer t = new Timer();
    event ElapsedEventHandler timerElapsed;

    public event ElapsedEventHandler Elapsed
    {
        add
        {
            t.Elapsed += value;
            timerElapsed += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            t.Elapsed -= value;
            timerElapsed -= value;
        }
    }

    public double Interval
    {
        get
        {
            return t.Interval;
        }
        set
        {
            t.Interval = value;
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        t.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        t.Stop();
    }

    public void RaiseElapsed()
    {
        if (timerElapsed != null)
            timerElapsed(null, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented in VB.NET with AddHandler

```
Public Class clsMain Inherits ServiceBase

Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
' in motion so your service can do its work.
gTimer.Interval = 1000  
gTimer.Enabled = True
AddHandler gTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf gTimer_Elapsed
End Sub

'When the timer is elapsed this event will be fired

Protected Sub gtimer_Elapsed(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
'Stop the timer and do some work
gTimer.Stop()
'Custom code
'Here
'Start to raise the elapsed event again
gTimer.Start()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro so take this with a pinch of salt but it works. I created a function and instead of putting my code into the timer sub I put it into the function. Then I merely called the function when I wanted it (in my case on page load) and then the timer code would fire at the interval times and simply call the function in the timer sub code.

Answer (score -2):

***Here is the easy answer***. (Assuming you're using a Windows form)

After dragging your timer control to your form, set the enabled property to true, and the Interval property to whatever you want the initial value to be. (100 is the default and will start the tick event immediately)

[image]

Then within your tick event, simply check the value of the Interval property. If it is not your desired value, set it. *It's that simple*. The same can be accomplished in your C# code if creating a timer on the fly.

[image]