# DispatcherTimer apply interval and execute immediately

Tags: c#, .net, timer

Basically when we apply some interval ie 5 sec we have to wait for it.

Is it possible to apply interval and execute timer immediately and don't wait 5 sec?
(I mean the interval time).

Any clue?

Thanks!!

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("!!!");
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want something to occur immediately, why not just execute it immediately?

Comment: @dlev Right But I want to see more elegant way...

Comment: I don't see what's inelegant about calling a method directly. You should probably create a new method, which is called in both places, but the idea is the same: if you want something to occur now, then just do it!

Comment: @dlev Initially I did as you suggesting but now I like the Austin Salonen solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Initially set the interval to zero and then raise it on a subsequent call.

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Timer)sender).Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    MessageBox.Show("!!!");
}
```

Comment: Jin's solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 21):

There are definitely more elegant solutions, but a hacky way is to just call the timer_Tick method after you set the interval initially. That'd be better than setting the interval on every tick.

Comment: Why is it better than setting the interval on every tick? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 6):

could try this:

```
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
timer.Interval = 0;
timer.Start();

//...

public void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (timer.Interval == 0) {
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Interval = SOME_INTERVAL;
    timer.Start();
    return;
  }

  //your timer action code here
}
```

Another way could be to use two event handlers (to avoid checking an "if" at every tick):

```
timer.Tick += Timer_TickInit;
timer.Interval = 0;
timer.Start();

//...

public void Timer_TickInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Interval = SOME_INTERVAL;
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick();
    timer.Start();
}

public void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //your timer action code here
}
```

However the cleaner way is what was already suggested:

```
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
timer.Interval = SOME_INTERVAL;
SomeAction();
timer.Start();

//...

public void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SomeAction();
}

public void SomeAction(){
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how I solved it:

```
dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(DispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
dispatcherTimer.Start();

DispatcherTimer_Tick(dispatcherTimer, new EventArgs());
```

Works for me without any issues.

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer:** This answer is not for the OP because he wants to use `DispatcherTimer` 
But if you do not have this limitation and you can use another Timer, then there is a cleaner solution

---

You can use [System.Threading.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer)

**The most important thing is setting `dueTime:0`**

```
System.Threading.Timer timer = new Timer(Callback, null, dueTime:0, period:10000);
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-threading-timer-ctor(system-threading-timercallback-system-object-system-int64-system-int64)) of the `dueTime` is the following

> The amount of time to delay before callback is invoked, in milliseconds. Specify Infinite to prevent the timer from starting. Specify zero (0) to start the timer immediately.

and your callback is like this

```
private void Callback(object? state) =>
{
}
```

Again this does not use `DispatcherTimer` but it could solve your problem

---

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6924148)