# How to let System.Windows.Forms.Timer to run the Tick handler immediately when starting?

Tags: c#, timer

The `Timer` following is `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`
C# Code:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.Interval = 10000;
myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(doSth);
myTimer.Start();
```

The timer will `doSth` every 10 seconds, but how to let it `doSth` immediately when starting?

I tried to create a custom timer which extends `Timer`, but I can't override the `Start` method.

For now, my code is:

```
myTimer.Start();
doSth(this, null);
```

I don't think it's good. How to improve it?

Comment: I think it's good. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924072/how-to-fire-timer-elapsed-event-immediatly also.

Comment: Freewind, you can change this myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(doSth);
look at the answer and example below that I've posted *** there is no need to pass any sender its get call when interval time ends.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's perfect. Don't change a thing.

Comment: Upvoted but I would personally have Swapped the two lines around to make sure I don't get weird threading-related collisions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of your exact requirements but why not put the code inside your timer callback inside another method?

e.g.

```
private void tmrOneSec_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DoTimerStuff();
}

private void DoTimerStuff()
{
    //put the code that was in your timer callback here
}
```

So that way you can just call DoTimerStuff() when your application starts up.

Answer (score 1):

The timer has to have form level scope, and it's not clear that you have that.  I whipped up a small example out of curiosity and it is working for me:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtLookup.Text = "test";
        DoSomething();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        txtLookup.Text += "ticking";
    }
```

Every 10 seconds it appends another "ticking" to the text in the textbox.

You say,

> "The timer will doSth every 10 seconds, but how to let it doSth immediately when starting?"

I say, call doSth immediately before calling the timer's start method