# Run loop outside onStart

Tags: c#, service

I'm making a service in C#.

I have the functions:

```
onStart();
copy();
onStop();
```

I was running `copy()` inside the `onStart()` function. But it was making the service status be set to *starting* forever, since the `copy()` function is a loop that runs infinitely (with a `Thread.Sleep()` inside), making the service unstoppable, unless I finish the proccess in Task Manager.

So, question is:

How can I get `copy()` to run at the end of `onStart()` and get `onStart()` not to wait for the completion of `copy()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start new Thread from OnStart so that your service return control back service controller.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Thread MyThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Starter));
    MyThread.Start();

    base.OnStart(args);
}

private void Starter()
{
   //Add your long running code here
}
```

You can also use Timer that will be started in OnStart and will keep your service running.

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);  // 30000 milliseconds = 30 seconds
    this.timer.AutoReset = true;
    this.timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer_Elapsed);
    this.timer.Start();
 }

 protected override void OnStop()
 {
      this.timer.Stop();
      this.timer = null;
 }

 private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
      //Your code goes here  
 }
```

Comment: What does the `base.OnStart(args);` do?

Comment: This will pass the argument to base class.

Comment: Do you have Starter defined as given in example

Comment: Yes. It had parameters, removing them got the error to dismiss.

Comment: Between the thread and timer option, which is best in your opinion? And the timer runs infinitely or just once? Should I put the loop with `Thread.Sleep` inside the `timer_Elapsed`?

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve, Most cases Timer is a better choice. We usually try to achieve similar periodic operation with for loop and sleep.

Comment: I've decided to use the Timers solution. I have a quick question: `new System.Timers.Timer(3000)` creates the timer but runs it only after the time period. How can I start it imediately and then run with the interval?

Comment: [Found it, nevermind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924072/how-to-fire-timer-elapsed-event-immediately)

Comment: I was busy and could not reply. That is good to know that you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a new `Thread` or use a `Timer`, with the code of an iteration in the `Tick` event.

Comment: I answered your question. Your question It's not about how to use a Thread or a Timer. And there are a lot of info about it in stackoverflow.